# Issue connecting Azure Storage Explorer to ADLS Gen 2

Tags: azure-data-lake-gen2, azure-storage-explorer

I am trying to connect to ADLS Gen 2 using Azure Storage Explorer. But I am getting an Authentication Error. Firewall is enabled to allow only certain IP's. I have added my system ip in ADLS using web UI. It's working fine. But when I connect through Storage Explorer, I am getting the same error. Can anyone help me how to fix this issue or how to whitelist IPs through Storage Explorer?

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yYOu.png)

Comment: hi @Rathesh, please provide what error are you getting ?

Comment: @SaiVamsi I added the error screenshot in the post. Please check it

Answer (score 0):

The above error happens because of a firewall issue. I got a similar error with Azure data explore. I resolved this error by adding an IP address under storage Account -> Go to Security + Networking -> Networking -> Firewalls and virtual networks -> Add or Enabled from selected virtual networks and IP addresses.

Make sure that you have appropriate RBAC roles to read blob data For example blob data reader, blob data contributor, and blob data owner.

[image]

Again If you got the same error better raise a support request. follow this [link](https://ms.portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Support/HelpAndSupportBlade/overview)

Comment: I tried to add IP already to the allowed list of IPs in storage account. It's not working.

Comment: @Rathesh, Refer this [MS_Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-network-security?tabs=azure-portal) Configure Azure Storage firewalls and virtual networks and also try to uninstall and reinstall back the app.

Comment: Tried that it's not working. Note: Storage Explorer is installed in Azure Virtual Desktop.

Comment: If you got the same error better raise a support request. follow this [link](https://ms.portal.azure.com/#view/Microsoft_Azure_Support/HelpAndSupportBlade/~/overview)